# Estructura JSON

Tags: c#, json

Estructura

```
{
    "Nombres": [{
            "Nombre": "Luis"
        },
        {
            "Nombre": "Edgar"
        },
        {
            "Nombre": "Daniel"
        }
    ]
}
```

En una app mando una estructura con una lista, por ejemplo

```
class Enviado
{
    public List<NombresModel> Nombres { get; set; }
}

class NombresModel
{
    public String Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Según en un post que vi de como se usaban la estructura de JSON, para llenar la lista de Nombres era así

```
Enviado E = new Enviado();
E.Nombres = new List<NombresModel>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    E.Nombres.Add(new NombresModel()
    {
        Nombre = "Luis" //Saco los nombres de una base de datos
    });
}
```

En otra app recibo dicho JSON e intento agregar los nombres en un listbox

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    Nombres.Items.Add(E.Nombres[i].Nombre);
}
```

Teniendo el

```
E.Nombres = new List<NombresModel>();
```

afuera del for (así estaba en el post que vi, solo se llamaba una vez) se me reemplaza el nombre por el siguiente y solo manda un nombre, pero si lo pongo dentro pasa algo similar, pero no manda ningún nombre, se queda vacío.

Comment: En ningún momento veo un json, veo objetos de c#

Comment: Es que no guardo el archivo como tal, lo envió, soy nuevo con json, lo que aprendí buscando lo intente poner en practica

Comment: Creo que no te estoy comprendiendo bien, el codigo de arriba son modelos, el siguiente apartado es una parte de una función para generar el modelo, la siguiente es otra que añade 5 o menos nombres

Comment: Si fuera un JSON tendrías que deserializarlo `List<NombresModel> datos= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NombresModel>>(json);` para convertirlo de JSON a objeto, pero tu estas tratando con un objeto directamente según pones en tu código

Comment: Ya le agregue mas o menos la estructura de como pienso debe ser.

Comment: Entonces con la línea de código que te he puesto debería generarte el modelo

Comment: Pero para ello debes agregar [Newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) a tus paquetes de NuGet

Comment: En el post que vi, y el cual si me ayudo, solo pone la estructura y como llamarlo en C#, lo de convertirlo a JSON lo hago después de llenar los datos, solo que la lista no me lo llena

Comment: Supongo que estas usando asp.net o me estoy equivocando?

Comment: Estoy usando .Net Framework

Comment: y lo que quieres es retornar el objeto convertido a JSON de nuevo?

Comment: No, llenar la lista Nombres, si coloco el E.Nombres = new List<NombresModel>(); fuera del for, el nombre se me reemplaza por el siguiente y no se llena la lista, si lo coloco dentro, se me formatea y lo manda vacio

Comment: Hola @MrLuisKiller Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Por favor intenta mejorar el título de tu pregunta para que sea más clara y esté acorde con el contenido. Te invito a que revises más recomendaciones en [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añadiendo la librería [Newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) a tu proyecto.

> Click derecho en referencias => Adminstrar paquetes de NuGet => Examinar, buscar e instalar

Entonces tus Modelos:

```
class Enviado
{
    public List<NombresModel> Nombres { get; set; }
}

class NombresModel
{
    public String Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Lo conviertes con el siguiente codigo:

```
List<NombresModel> datos= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NombresModel>>(json);
```

Entonces te genera un modelo `List<NombresModel>` con una lista de `NombresModel`

Comment: Te sere sincero, me refería a llenar la lista de Nombres, mi culpa por no ser mas especifico.

Comment: Esto llena la lista de nombres