# Enviar lista de string por Postman

Tags: c#, json, api

Estoy haciendo un método en una API que tiene esta firma:

```
public HttpResponseMessage CrearReqMet ([FromUri] CrearReq request)
```

La clase CrearReq es así:

```
public class CrearReq
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Lista de elementos
        /// </summary>
        public ListaValores ListaValoresReporte { get; set; }
    }
```

Y la clase ListaValores es así:

```
public class ListaValores
    {
        public List<string> Encabezados { get; set; }
        public List<string> Valores { get; set; }
    }
```

Y quiero enviar valores en esas listas de string por Postman. Trate enviandolos por el body de esta manera pero no funciona, llega null la clase CrearReq:

```
{
    "ListaValoresReporte" : {
        "Encabezados" : [
            "Nombre",
            "Apellido"
        ],
        "Valores" : [
            "Ignacio",
            "Sanmartino"
        ]
    }
}
```

Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Comment: Estas intentando enviarlo al controlador?

Comment: Si, en el controlador me llega null tambien.

Comment: y supongo que es una web asp.net, me equivoco?

Comment: Si, Web Api en C#

Comment: Vale, entonces puedes desde la vista convertir el json en string con `JSON.stringify(tuJson)` y utilizar [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/370459/101499)

Comment: Pero yo lo que quiero es saber como envio una lista de string por Postman, quiero saber cual seria la sintaxsis de ese envio.

Comment: Entonces no entiendo bien tu pregunta, porque parecia que querías comunicar una vista con un controlador

Comment: Pero puse esto al final de la pregunta: _Y quiero enviar valores en esas listas de string por Postman. Trate enviandolos por el body de esta manera pero no funciona, llega null la clase CrearReq:_
Era para decirles que lo que quiero es enviar una lista de string por Postman que no se como se hace. Capaz que lo suba arriba o lo aclare mejor entonces

Answer (score 0):

Dejo la solución por si alguien la necesita:

```
{
    "ListaValoresReporte" : {
        "Encabezados" : ["ASD", "ASD1"],
        "Valores" : ["DSA"]
    }
}
```

Comment: No has dicho cómo y por qué esas líneas solucionan el problema. Cuál era el error?

Comment: Es la misma estructura del json que dejo en la pregunta, por lo tanto no creo que esta respuesta sea la solución. Si hubiera colocado que cambio el atributo de `[FromUri]` por `[FromBody]` fuera mas aceptable la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El postman se tiene que configurar con el tipo de datos que estas enviando.
En este caso, entiendo que es tipo json.

[image: configuracion body]

El formato de los datos enviados lo veo correcto.