# Recoger datos de un JSON y guardarlos en variables

Tags: c#, json, .net

tengo un archivo JSON y me gustaria sacar todos los datos de ahí y guardarlos en variables para luego tratarlos.

```
 {
    "codcli": "      17",
    "nomcli": "BICICLETA ASTURIANA, S.L.",
    "codrep": "       4",
    "telcli": "900.222.113",
    "e_mail": "comercial@biciasturiana.es"
  }
```

Este seria un ejemplo de lo que hay en el JSON. Mi proyecto es uno de consola de C#.

Tengo la clase json con esto puesto.

```
class Cliente
{
    public Clientes[] clientes { get; set; }

}
class Clientes
{
    public string codcli { get; set; }
    public string nomcli { get; set; }
    public string codrep { get; set; }
    public string telcli { get; set; }
    public string e_mail { get; set; }
}
```

Mi clase principal es esta

```
        private static void leerJSON()
    {
                    StreamReader r = new StreamReader("file.json");
        string jsonString = r.ReadToEnd();
        var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cliente>(jsonString.Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", ""));
        string codigo = m.clientes[0].ToString();
        string nombre = m.clientes[1].ToString();
        string representante = m.clientes[2].ToString();
        string telefono = m.clientes[3].ToString();
        string email = m.clientes[4].ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(codigo + " " + nombre + " " + representante + " " + telefono + " " + email);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

La variable jsonString recoge todos los campos =

> ```
>   jsonString  "[\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"       1\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"SPORTS ABC\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       1\",\n    \"telcli\": \"93.345.67.89\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@abcsports.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"       2\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"SPORTI, S.A.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       4\",\n    \"telcli\": \"93.222.11.23\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@sporti.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"       3\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"DEPORTES REUNIDOS, S.L.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       1\",\n    \"telcli\": \"91.234.11.33\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@reunidos.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"       4\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"ANDA-ANDA, S.A.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       2\",\n    \"telcli\": \"93.234.23.23\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@andaanda.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"      18\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"SA VELO, S.A.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       3\",\n    \"telcli\": \"902.222.333\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@savelo.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"       6\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"VIATHLON, S.L.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       1\",\n    \"telcli\": \"902.555.231\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@viathlon.com\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"       7\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"DEPOR-CAMPO, S.L.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       4\",\n    \"telcli\": \"902.411.113\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@deporcampo.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"       8\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"NEU BLANCA, S.A.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       3\",\n    \"telcli\": \"93.414.13.12\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@neublanca.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"       9\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"EUROFRED\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       2\",\n    \"telcli\": \"902.412.323\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@eurofred.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"      10\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"SKI, S.L.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       1\",\n    \"telcli\": \"902.567.111\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@skisl.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"      11\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"NIEVE BLANCA, S.A.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       4\",\n    \"telcli\": \"902.567.213\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@nieveblanca.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"      12\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"REPROSPORT\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       3\",\n    \"telcli\": \"902.137.420\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@reprosport.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"      13\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"MG-DEPORTES\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       2\",\n    \"telcli\": \"924.11.11.11\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@mgdeportes.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"      14\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"DEPORTES LOPEZ, S.L.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       2\",\n    \"telcli\": \"95.234.31.24\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@deporlopez.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"      15\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"SPORTS MARÍA\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       4\",\n    \"telcli\": \"91.567.65.43\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@sportsmaria.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"CONTADO\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"Clientes contado\",\n    \"codrep\": null,\n    \"telcli\": \"\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"      16\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"DEPORTES DE ARAGÓN, S.L.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       2\",\n    \"telcli\": \"900.456.7.89\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@deportesaragon.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"      17\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"BICICLETA ASTURIANA, S.L.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       4\",\n    \"telcli\": \"900.222.113\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@biciasturiana.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"       5\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"DEPORTES CANTABRIA\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       3\",\n    \"telcli\": \"902.222.333\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@deportescantabria.es\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"      19\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"DEPORTES PALMERA, S.A.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       2\",\n    \"telcli\": \"902.333.444\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@palmera.com\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"      20\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"DEPORTES DE RUEDAS, S.L.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       4\",\n    \"telcli\": \"902.123.433\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@druedas.com\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"codcli\": \"      21\",\n    \"nomcli\": \"BICIS LA REAL, S.L.\",\n    \"codrep\": \"       3\",\n    \"telcli\": \"902.400.187\",\n    \"e_mail\": \"comercial@bicislareal.com\"\n  }\n]"
> ```

Me sale este error cuando compilo

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'JsonA3ERP.json' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
> Path '', line 1, position 1.'

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Estructura JSON](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/370450/estructura-json)

Comment: Has mirado que te devuelve `jsonString`? El error está claro, el texto que le pasas no tiene estructura json

Comment: si claro y me devuelve el JSON pero en una linea todo

Comment: El problema podría estar en los retornos de carro que aparecen (\n). Por hacer una prueba, podrías pasarle al DeserializeObject la cadena tal como hace @Marc en su respuesta. Si asi funciona, yo probaría a eliminar los retornos de carro de la variable que lee desde el archivo

Comment: Incluso mas sencillo, intenta `dynamic m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<json>(jsonString.Replace("\n",""));` Ya que estamos, me hace daño a los ojos ese dynamic. Te recomendaria usar el tipo correcto o al menos `var`

Comment: vale he quitado el dynamic y el retorno de carro pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Son los espacios, haz replace de ellos `jsonString.Replace(" ","")`

Comment: y mi pregunta es la siguiente, en el error me da algo de hacer una lista. Puede ser porque mi clase no es una lista? ¿Como puedo hacer una lista de json?

Comment: A ver..yo me he fiado de la clase que has puesto, pero lo mejor es que dejes que la cree el propio VS. Copia todo el json del archivo, y en el vs vas a editar/Pegado especial/Pegar json como clases y automaticamente te crea las clases necesarias de forma correcta. Efectivamente, lo mas logico es que necesites una lista de tu clase `json`

Comment: sabrias pasarme el codigo para ejecutarlo? porque no me va

Comment: he modificado todo el codigo de mi proyecto en la pregunta

Comment: Ya tienes demasiadas ediciones en la pregunta... esto es un [Problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3360/101499) te recomiendo que antes de escribir una pregunta pienses bien el problema y lo plantees bien para que recibas una buena respuesta

Comment: El problema aca es que te dieron una respuesta a tu problema original. Y ahora, que modificaste todo, esa respuesta es invalida. Asi no funciona el sitio, vos haces una pregunta y recibis una respuesta. Si tenes otra pregunta, que no tiene nada que ver con la original, haces una nueva pregunta...

Answer (score 1):

Usando la función `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` de la librería [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) podrías conseguir lo que buscas:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
json js = obj.ToObject(typeof(json));
```

Puedes ver las pruebas en el siguiente [enlace](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DPbIfb).

Comment: JsonConvert es una función de una librería externa llamada [Newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) debe agregarla desde NuGet

Comment: Correcto, se me pasó ponerlo, lo añado a la respuesta

Comment: Si, asi lo tengo de hecho pero no me funciona yo necesito que sea un proceso automatico por asi decirlo

Comment: He editado la pregunta para que lo veais bien el codigo

Answer (score 0):

si este es tu json que deseas Deserializar

```
{
    "codcli": "      17",
    "nomcli": "BICICLETA ASTURIANA, S.L.",
    "codrep": "       4",
    "telcli": "900.222.113",
    "e_mail": "comercial@biciasturiana.es"
  }
```

entonces solo con esto bastara y que tus propiedas sean [Nullable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

```
StreamReader r = new StreamReader("file.json");
 string jsonString = r.ReadToEnd();
 var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cliente>(jsonString);
 string codigo = m?.Codcli;
  string nombre = m?.Nomcli;
  string representante = m?.Codrep;
  string telefono = m?.Telcli;
  string email = m?.EMail;
```

te recomiendo esta [Pagina](https://app.quicktype.io/) para que pases tu json a classes c#, si el primer json esta incompleto, entonces edita tu pregunta y pon el json correctamente

```
[JsonProperty("codcli")]
        public string Codcli { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nomcli")]
        public string Nomcli { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("codrep")]
        public string Codrep { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("telcli")]
        public string Telcli { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("e_mail")]
        public string EMail { get; set; }
```

[image: Resultado]